# How to get subset of an object array filtered on items of (sub)property array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

What would be the best approach (possibly async) for extracting a sub-set from an array (of objects) where we want to filter/search for items of a property that also is an array?

Lets say, from following list we want only items that have 'Green' in the "basecolors" property (sub)array. And we would get a resulting array of 5 items: 1, 7, 8, 11, 17.

Example:

```
export const COLORS: Color[] = [
    { name: 'Aqua', hex: '#00FFFF', basecolors: ['Blue', 'Green'] },        // 1
    { name: 'Black', hex: '#000000', basecolors: ['Black'] },       // 2
    { name: 'Blue', hex: '#0000FF', basecolors: ['Blue'] },     // 3
    { name: 'Brown', hex: '#A52A2A', basecolors: ['Red'] },     // 4
    { name: 'Fuchsia', hex: '#FF00FF', basecolors: ['Blue', 'Red'] },       // 5
    { name: 'Gray', hex: '#808080', basecolors: ['Black', 'White'] },       // 6
    { name: 'Green', hex: '#008000', basecolors: ['Green'] },       // 7
    { name: 'Lime', hex: '#00FF00', basecolors: ['Green'] },        // 8
    { name: 'Maroon', hex: '#800000', basecolors: ['Red'] },        // 9
    { name: 'Navy', hex: '#000080', basecolors: ['Blue'] },     // 10
    { name: 'Olive', hex: '#808000', basecolors: ['Green', 'Red'] },        // 11
    { name: 'Orange', hex: '#FFA500', basecolors: ['Red', 'Yellow'] },      // 12
    { name: 'Pink', hex: '#FFC0CB', basecolors: ['Red'] },      // 13
    { name: 'Purple', hex: '#800080', basecolors: ['Blue', 'Red'] },        // 14
    { name: 'Red', hex: '#FF0000', basecolors: ['Red'] },       // 15
    { name: 'Silver', hex: '#C0C0C0', basecolors: ['Black', 'White'] },     // 16
    { name: 'Teal', hex: '#008080', basecolors: ['Blue', 'Green'] },        // 17
    { name: 'White', hex: '#FFFFFF', basecolors: ['White'] },       // 18
    { name: 'Yellow', hex: '#FFFF00', basecolors: ['Yellow'] }      // 19
];
```

Now we can pass the object to array named: colorsList - e.g:

```
colorsList: Color[] = COLORS;
```

and now we filter to get resulting sub-array, which will have only items of 'basecolors' containing 'Green'
I am looking for something like this:

```
const greenColorsList: Color[] = this.colorsList.filter(item => item.basecolors.contains('Green'));
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you shared? That looks like it should accomplish this?

Comment: Now I know what is wrong - a victim of several languages. ' The item.basecolors.contains('Green') should be:  item.basecolors.includes('Green').

Comment: this has nothing to do with angular, this is just a JS question ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
const greenColorsList: Color[] = this.colorsList.filter(item => item.basecolors.includes('Green'));
```

Async way - e.g:

```
const searchPhrase$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

searchPhrase$.next('Green');

const items$ = searchPhrase$.pipe(
  map((phrase = '') => phrase.length > 0
    ? this.colorsList
      .filter(({ basecolors }) => basecolors.indexOf(phrase) >= 0).slice(0)
    : this.colorsList
  )
);

items$.subscribe(colors => {
  this.greenColorsList = colors;
});
```